# Accessing .env in PHP returns Uncaught error: Array callback must have exactly two elements

Tags: php

I would like to store certain information in a .env, access it in PHP and append that information to my `POST` request. However, when I try and do that I get the error:

```
[500]: POST /proxy.php?url=https://www.expensify.com/api?command=Authenticate - Uncaught Error: Array callback must have exactly two elements
```

It seems I am not actually accessing any .env variables:

```
$name= $_ENV("NAME");
$password= $_ENV("PASS");
print_r('name', $name);
echo $name;
...
    $ch = curl_init();
    $userID= $POST['userID'];
    $userSecret = $POST['userSecret'];
    $postData = array(
        $name=>$name,
        $password=>$password,
        $userID=>$userID,
        $userSecret=>$userSecret
    );
    $data = http_build_query($postData);
```

and in my .env

```
NAME=***
PASS=***
```

Comment: `$someVariable()` is the syntax for [variable functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php). You want [array access](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.accessing) instead.

Comment: `$_ENV['NAME']` not `$_ENV('NAME')`. Also, `$_POST` not `$POST`. Also, are you actually using _phpdotenv_ or somesuch to load `.env` files into `$_ENV`? (There is no such default behavior in PHP.)

Answer (score 1):

`$_ENV` is array, but you call it as function `$_ENV('NAME')`.

Use `$_ENV['NAME']`